# Composite facet for hibernate search

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I have two entities: `Action` and `User` with many-to-one relationship.
I search for actions and I'd like to have a `user full name` facet, but instead of a `full_name` column in the database, I have `first_name` and `last_name`.

Is there any way to create a combined facet in hibernate search that would use `firstName` and `lastName` together? Or is there a way to create a combined field `fullName` that will exist in the search index (with a facet) but not in the database?

The mapping is the following:

```
@Entity
public class Action {

    ...

    @IndexEmbedded
    private User user;

}


@Entity
public class User {

    ...

    @Facet
    @Field(analyze = Analyze.NO)
    private String firstName;

    @Facet
    @Field(analyze = Analyze.NO)
    private String lastName;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use @Facet and @Field on a method of your User object.

So you can define something like:

```
@Facet
@Field
public String getFullName() {
   return new StringJoiner(" ").add(firstName).add(lastName).toString();
}
```